# Назначение прав с++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Мне необходимо назначить права на файл пользователям, которых можно выбрать из списка.

```
string namea = AddName();

FileInfo ^ info3 = gcnew FileInfo(name);
FileSecurity^ fSec = info3->GetAccessControl();

fSec->AddAccessRule(gcnew FileSystemAccessRule(namea,
    FileSystemRights::Read, AccessControlType::Allow));

info3->SetAccessControl(fSec);
```

Функция `AddName()` возвращает строку namea вида: `"Admin-PC\\User"`, но ее не удается передать в `FileSystemAccessRule`, так как строка не является объектом класса `System::Security::Principal::IdentityReference ^`.

Это можно сделать только в явном виде, вот так:

```
fSec->AddAccessRule(gcnew FileSystemAccessRule("Admin-PC\\User", 
FileSystemRights::Read, AccessControlType::Allow));
```

Скажите, возможно ли преобразование? Создание объекта этого класса (я не смогла воспользоваться конструктором)?

```
string AddName()
{
    char buffer[256];
    DWORD size = 256;
    GetComputerNameA(buffer, &size);
    String^ buf = gcnew String(buffer);
    String^polpol;
    polpol = Convert::ToString(comboBox1->SelectedItem);
    string st1 = SystemToStl(buf) + "\\\\";
    string st2 = SystemToStl(polpol);
    string st3 = st1 + st2;
    return st3;
}
```

Comment: AddName() возвращает строку namea вида: "Admin-PC\\User" - функция возвращает строку с двумя \\

Comment: `string` (с маленькой буквы) - нативный тип (`std::string`). `FileSystemAccessRule` принимает `String^` (с большой буквы) - управляемый тип (`System::String^`).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо!!! Вы не знаете как преобразовать string in String^?

Comment: А что у вас в методе `AddName`?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, плохо выглядящая функция...

                       

           string AddName()
                        {   char buffer[256];
    DWORD size = 256;
    GetComputerNameA(buffer,&size);
 String^ buf = gcnew String(buffer);

 String^polpol;
    polpol = Convert::ToString(comboBox1->SelectedItem);

    string st1 = SystemToStl(buf) + "\\\\";
 string st2 = SystemToStl(polpol);
 string st3 = st1+st2;

 return st3;
}

Вот так она выглядит...

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, Я даже с форматированием комментариев не справляюсь!!!

Comment: В комментариях невозможно форматирование. И вообще, не пишите код в комментариях. Редактируйте вопрос, добавляя в него все необходимое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш метод `AddName` можно сократить и упростить до следующего:

```
String^ AddName()
{
    char buffer[256];
    DWORD size = 256;
    GetComputerNameA(buffer, &size);
    String^ buf = gcnew String(buffer);
    String^ polpol = Convert::ToString(comboBox1->SelectedItem);
    return buf + "\\\\" + polpol;
}
```

В результате он возвращает нужный тип. Дополнительные преобразования не нужны.
Кстати, имя метода мне кажется неправильным. Он, вроде, ничего не добавляет.

---

Так как вы работаете с WinForms на платформе .NET, то есть смысл весь код, который возможно, писать на *управляемом* C++/CLI, не прибегая к *нативному* С++ и WinAPI.

Имя компьютера можно получить [намного проще](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.machinename?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
String^ GetName()
{
    return Environment::MachineName + "\\\\" + comboBox1->SelectedItem;
}
```

В данном случае у `SelectedItem` будет автоматически вызван `ToString()`.
В принципе, теперь можно вообще выкинуть этот метод, т. к. код сократился до одной строки.

Comment: Неюникодные функции и char при том, что тут .net? :(

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ НЕВЕРОЯТНОЕ КОСМИЧЕСКОЕ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!